# Sensor simulation using node-red

Tags: node-red

I'm new to node-red and I would like to create a simulation of different sensors (temperature, moisture, airQuality ...) that would return random data. I also need to create events, for example a fire in a house that would obviously increase the values returned by the simulated temperature sensor.

Does anybody know how to "trigger" that kind of event using node-red?

Comment: As it stands this question is probably too broad to get a proper answer, there are many many ways to do this but they all require you to define the ranges and rates of inputs. Also to decide what sort of input you want (mqtt, http, gio or any number of other methods...)

Comment: It's good to know that there are indeed many ways to do it with node-red.
My approach is quiet naive as I just want to have a set of random variable as an input, send it every second and change their values according to an event I'll be able to trigger at anytime. 
I'll work on it, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Scheduler node: 
http://tech.scargill.net/node-red-scheduler/

You should use it in combination with a function node were you can use random functions to simulate your data.